# How is it that "sizeof (char[0])" compiles just fine with GCC

Tags: c, gcc

A colleague of mine inserted a `(void) sizeof (char[0])` at the end of a multi line, macro as an alternative to `do {...} while (0)` apparently. I have looked around but I can't find any reference to it and it surprises me that it even compiles.

Is it valid C? I would love a reference to the std.

Comment: If it had been `(void) sizeof(char);`, would you have expected that to compile?

Comment: How is `(void) sizeof (char[0])` an alternative to `do {...} while (0)`? If `sizeof (char[0])` were valid, it would be `0`. If you want to write `(void)0`, just write `(void)0`.

Comment: Alternative in the sense that it forces a semicolon at the end aparently.

Comment: @JeffMercado Yes, I would, since sizeof(char) is one and the cast to void kills warnings about unused. Should I not expect that to compile? I'm here to learn.

Comment: Why would anyone do this? I'm all for using C and not fearing that people don't know the language, but this seems like someone's *trying* to obfuscate things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you compile with `gcc -pedantic`, you'll get a warning message:

```
warning: ISO C forbids zero-size array [-Wpedantic]
```

The latest draft of the C standard, [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), section 6.7.6.2 (Array declarators) paragraph 1 says:

> If the expression is a constant expression, it shall have a value
>   greater than zero.

This is part of a constraint, so `char[0]` is a constraint violation, requiring a diagnostic from any conforming C compiler.

(It's not 100% clear that that particular clause applies to the type name `char[0]` in the absence of a declared object, but the general idea is that standard C does not support zero-length arrays.)

gcc supports zero-sized arrays as an extension, [documented here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.1.0/gcc/Zero-Length.html).

Comment: 6.7.6/2 says "Each declarator declares one identifier, ".  `char[0]` doesn't declare any identifier, so it's not a declarator and therefore 6.7.6.2's constraints don't apply.  (Well, that's what the text seems to say -- whether that was the intent is another matter...)

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Good point. `char[0]` is a *type-name*. 6.7.7 "Type names" says that a type name "is syntactically a declaration for a function or an object of that type that omits the identifier". I presume the intent is that the same constraint applies -- or perhaps it's stated explicitly somewhere else.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: BTW, [the question you linked to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30557710/do-parentheses-make-a-difference-when-determining-the-size-of-an-array) in the comment on the now deleted answer doesn't apply; the parentheses are part of the syntax of `sizeof` (as distinct from applying `sizeof` to an expression).

Comment: Yeah that was more of a side-track

Answer (score 2):

C11 6.5.3.4/2:

> The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an
>   expression **or the parenthesized name of a type**.

/4:

> When applied to an operand that has array type, the result is the total number of bytes in the array.

C11 6.7.7 defines *type name*, especially /2:

> In several contexts, it is necessary to specify a type. This is accomplished using a type name, which is **syntactically** a declaration for a function or an object of that type that omits the identifier.

So `char[0]` is a *type name* because it is syntactically a declaration for an object that omits the identifier. (Semantically it's invalid because zero-sized arrays are not allowed, but it is still a *type name*).

---

Based on these quotes I would say that `sizeof` is underspecified. 6.5.3.4/2 doesn't restrict *type name* to type names that would be a legal declaration if an identifier were included.   6.5.3.4/4 does say "the array" but [nobody can agree on what "array" means in C anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546449/what-is-the-definition-of-array-in-c) and I don't think this clearly implies anything about `char[0]`.

Based on these quotes I would say that it is inconclusive.