# Access all object elements as an array

Tags: c++

If I have created a class like this:

```
struct test{
  int a;
  int b;
  string c;
};
```

and wanted to iterate through each data member as if it was an array how could i do it?(Assuming the number of members may change in a future update.)

Comment: https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get

Comment: Would be straight-forward if you could hold the data members in a tuple.

Comment: If all members data types is the same you can just cast pointer to your stuct to pointer to members type. But it is trick.

Comment: *Why* do you want that? What is the *actual* problem that makes you need something like that? Perhaps a `struct` isn't the correct data structure for your design? Perhaps even the design is flawed? Oh and please read [about the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem since you're question is an example of one.

Comment: @DmytroDadyka Iterating the data members directly technically has undefined behaviour.

Comment: It's not a specific problem I was just wondering if something like this could be done since i learned a similar thing could be done if all data members were the same type.

Answer (score -1):

Immediately, I note that C ++ does not support arrays of elements of different types, so there is no solution in your case. But with identical members you can create an array of pointers to members and use it in the loop:

```
struct test {
   int a0 = 0;
   int a1 = 1;
   int a2 = 2;
   int a3 = 3;
   virtual ~test() {};
};

int main()
{
   test t;
   int* ptr[4] = { &t.a0, &t.a1, &t.a2, &t.a3 };
   for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(ptr) / sizeof(int*); i++)
      std::cout << *ptr[i] << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"there is no solution in your case"* Check out this link: https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get

Comment: Also [`boost::any`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/any.html).

Comment: You should at least mention that it is undefined behavior.

Comment: Here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48463521 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/48463923/2752075

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, Now I agree with you.