# Is it possible to override the default behavior of getting a struct member in C++?

Tags: c++, properties, overriding, getter

Similar to the  `@property` tag in python, I am trying to figure out if it is possible to override the behavior of a getter in c++ without having to make a function call.

Basically, is it possible to do the following in c++:

```
class vector2(class):
    def __init__(self):
        self.values = [1,2]

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.values[0]
pos = vector2()
my_var = pos.x
```

Is the best solution to just write getters and setters?

Comment: You can fake it with implicit conversion, but IMO it's not worth it. Has corner cases, and can inhibit optimization. It's better to use idiomatic C++, which is just to use methods directly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8368512/does-c11-have-c-style-properties . MSVC _does_ have a nonstandard `declspec` extension for dynamic properties, but it's not supported by g++. clang supports it behind a flag.

Comment: For that example in particular, you would overload `operator[]` but in general, this is not possible in C++

Comment: The C++ way is getters and setters.  `int get_x() const { return values[0]; }` and `void set_x(int value) { values[0] = value; }`

Comment: For going the other way array, overloading the `[]`, this answer is pretty cool - use a `constexpr` array of pointer-to-members and do a lookup. Optimizes down pretty close to what an inlined getter method would do: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48464023/1863938

Comment: Please review "Tell, Don't ask" articles.  getters and setters simply waste your time - so simply put the code that uses the instance data in the object.

Comment: @parktomatomi I checked and a switch is better. https://godbolt.org/z/KrdzSK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no, you can't do that.

---

For a 2D vector that you can access as an array, I would do something like this:

```
struct Vec2 {
  float x;
  float y;

  const float &operator[](const size_t i) const {
    static_assert(sizeof(Vec2) == 2 * sizeof(float));
    assert(i < 2);
    return (&x)[i];
  }

  float &operator[](const size_t i) {
    return const_cast<float &>(std::as_const(*this)[i]);
  }
};
```

So you can access the member variables directly or use the overloaded subscript operator.

```
Vec2 v{4, 5};
v.x += 9;
v[1] = -3;
```

---

In general, getters and setters are called explicitly. A naming convention I've seen quite a lot of is giving the getter and setter the same name.

```
class Foo {
public:
  int member() const {
    return hidden;
  }

  void member(const int value) {
    hidden = value;
  }

private:
  int hidden;
};
```

This naming convention makes access very clean but still makes it clear that a function call is taking place.

```
Foo f;
f.member(5);
int five = f.member();
```

Comment: `return (&x)[i];` That doesn't look safe.

Comment: @SneakyTurtle The order of members is guaranteed but the padding isn't. With the assertions in place it should be fine.

Comment: `(&x)[1]` is pedantically UB.(`x` is not an array, and can only be treated as `float[1]`).