# Is there any way in Rust to convert between a pointer and a U64 without UB?

Tags: rust

I made a lock-free stack for 32bit systems, using the classic algorithm of compare and swap of the head pointer. To prevent the ABA problem, I also have to store a monotonically increasing counter and swap it with the pointer. On a 64bit system this means stuffing the counter into the unused high bits of the pointer. In a 32bit system it's a little easier as you can use a 32bit pointer, a 32bit counter, and stuff them both into an AtomicU64.

For the 64bit system, you can store the stuffed pointer as an AtomicPtr. It's invalid without masking off the counter bits, but AFAIK that doesn't violate [pointer provenance](https://rust-lang.github.io/unsafe-code-guidelines/glossary.html). For a 32bit system, you really have no choice but to use AtomicU64, and then cast half of it to the pointer. That's undefined behavior in Rust, if I understand it correctly. The compiler does the right thing, but it's still UB.

The only way I can see to avoid the UB is implement the whole thing in C, because pointer provenance [doesn't apply there yet (PDF)](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2676.pdf). Or in assembly where a byte is thankfully still just a byte. Is there any other way to solve this problem in stable or nightly Rust?

I'd love to publish this as a library, but if it has UB, nobody would use it.

I really wish there was a way to tell the compiler: this is a pointer of unknown provenance, it could alias anything, hands off.

Comment: of course C does pointer provenance since a long time. There is multiple case where if you are not careful you C code will blow up if you mess with pointer doing wrong thing. https://stackoverflow.com/q/47220212/7076153

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, the only way to do this are the nightly functions
[`expose_addr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/primitive.pointer.html#method.expose_addr)
and [`from_exposed_addr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/ptr/fn.from_exposed_addr.html).

You could use them behind a feature flag, and put an explanation for this limitation in your library's documentation / readme.
As far as I'm concerned, this is all the due diligence currently required for a library.

Note that pointer provenance is still a hot topic, and many popular libraries ([example](https://github.com/ferrilab/bitvec/blob/main/src/ptr/span.rs#L275)) aren't fully compliant yet.

Notice also that while this may technically be UB in Rust, LLVM is most likely not going to take advantage of that, due to it's memory model being primarily based on C. (And unsafe Rust not using C's strict-aliasing rules). Just assume that all your reference parameters have a `noalias` attribute, and reason about if that would cause UB under LLVM, simple as that ;).

This will trip up miri though, which does not seem to have a mechanism for locally turning of errors [yet](https://github.com/rust-lang/miri/issues/797).
Fortunately, since miri is usually used with the nightly toolchain,
you would be good to go there.

Comment: Those functions are exactly what I was wishing for, I will take your advise about feature gating them, and add a warning to the docs.